# Disappearing data, what's going on? Pebble newbie

Tags: javascript, c, pebble-sdk, pebble-js

Brand new and naive to pebble SDK and C but lots of experience in other languages. Which means I'm probably going to be embarrassed when someone solves this for me very easily but... I have two files in a watchface project based on the tutorials... I'm pulling in different data but it all works just like the getting started tutorial up until the point that the code updates one of the text layers with... nothing. It's got me puzzled becuase the data it's supposed to be putting in there appears fine in the console log so it's definitely getting passed over. Anyways, here's the C

```
include 
#define KEY_MONTHMILES 0
#define KEY_MONTHELEVATION 1
#define KEY_TOTALMILES 2
#define KEY_TOTALELEVATION 3

static Window *s_main_window;
static TextLayer *s_time_layer;
static BitmapLayer *s_background_layer;
static GBitmap *s_background_bitmap;
static TextLayer *s_weather_layer;

static void update_time() {
    // Get a tm structure
    time_t temp = time(NULL); 
    struct tm *tick_time = localtime(&temp);

    // Create a long-lived buffer
    static char buffer[] = "00:00";

    // Write the current hours and minutes into the buffer
    if(clock_is_24h_style() == true) {
        // Use 24 hour format
        strftime(buffer, sizeof("00:00"), "%H:%M", tick_time);
    } else {
        // Use 12 hour format
        strftime(buffer, sizeof("00:00"), "%I:%M", tick_time);
    }

    // Display this time on the TextLayer
    text_layer_set_text(s_time_layer, buffer);
}

static void tick_handler(struct tm *tick_time, TimeUnits units_changed) {
    update_time();
}

static void inbox_received_callback(DictionaryIterator *iterator, void *context) {
    // Store incoming information
    static char monthlyMiles_buffer[128];
    static char monthlyElevation_buffer[128];
    static char yearlyMiles_buffer[128];
    static char yearlyElevation_buffer[128];

    // Read first item
    Tuple *t = dict_read_first(iterator);

    // For all items
    while(t != NULL) {
        // Which key was received?
        switch(t->key) {
            case KEY_MONTHMILES:
                snprintf(monthlyMiles_buffer, sizeof(monthlyMiles_buffer), "%d", (int)t->value->int32);
                break;
            case KEY_MONTHELEVATION:
                snprintf(monthlyElevation_buffer, sizeof(monthlyElevation_buffer), "%d", (int)t->value->int32);
                break;
            case KEY_TOTALMILES:
                snprintf(yearlyMiles_buffer, sizeof(yearlyMiles_buffer), "%d", (int)t->value->int32);
                break;
            case KEY_TOTALELEVATION:
                snprintf(yearlyElevation_buffer, sizeof(yearlyElevation_buffer), "%d", (int)t->value->int32);
                break;
            default:
                APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "Key %d not recognized!", (int)t->key);
                break;
        }

        // Look for next item
        t = dict_read_next(iterator);
    }
    text_layer_set_text(s_weather_layer, monthlyMiles_buffer);
}

static void inbox_dropped_callback(AppMessageResult reason, void *context) {
    APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "Message dropped!");
}

static void outbox_failed_callback(DictionaryIterator *iterator, AppMessageResult reason, void *context) {
    APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "Outbox send failed!");
}

static void outbox_sent_callback(DictionaryIterator *iterator, void *context) {
    APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_INFO, "Outbox send success!");
}

static void main_window_load(Window *window) {
    // Create GBitmap, then set to created BitmapLayer
    s_background_bitmap = gbitmap_create_with_resource(RESOURCE_ID_BG_IMAGE);
    s_background_layer = bitmap_layer_create(GRect(0, 0, 144, 168));
    bitmap_layer_set_bitmap(s_background_layer, s_background_bitmap);
    layer_add_child(window_get_root_layer(window), bitmap_layer_get_layer(s_background_layer)); 

    // Create time TextLayer
    s_time_layer = text_layer_create(GRect(0, 60, 144, 50));
    text_layer_set_background_color(s_time_layer, GColorClear);
    text_layer_set_text_color(s_time_layer, GColorWhite);
    layer_add_child(window_get_root_layer(window), text_layer_get_layer(s_time_layer));

    // Improve the layout to be more like a watchface
    text_layer_set_font(s_time_layer, fonts_get_system_font(FONT_KEY_BITHAM_42_BOLD));
    text_layer_set_text_alignment(s_time_layer, GTextAlignmentCenter);

    // Make sure the time is displayed from the start
    update_time();

    // Create temperature Layer
    s_weather_layer = text_layer_create(GRect(0, 130, 144, 25));
    text_layer_set_background_color(s_weather_layer, GColorClear);
    text_layer_set_text_color(s_weather_layer, GColorWhite);
    text_layer_set_text_alignment(s_weather_layer, GTextAlignmentCenter);
    text_layer_set_text(s_weather_layer, "Loading...");
    text_layer_set_font(s_weather_layer, fonts_get_system_font(FONT_KEY_GOTHIC_14));
    layer_add_child(window_get_root_layer(window), text_layer_get_layer(s_weather_layer));
}

static void main_window_unload(Window *window) {
    // Destroy TextLayer
    text_layer_destroy(s_time_layer);

    // Destroy GBitmap
    gbitmap_destroy(s_background_bitmap);

    // Destroy BitmapLayer
    bitmap_layer_destroy(s_background_layer);

    // Destroy weather elements
    text_layer_destroy(s_weather_layer);
}

static void init() {
    // Create main Window element and assign to pointer
    s_main_window = window_create();

    // Set handlers to manage the elements inside the Window
    window_set_window_handlers(s_main_window, (WindowHandlers) {
        .load = main_window_load,
        .unload = main_window_unload
    });

    // Show the Window on the watch, with animated=true
    window_stack_push(s_main_window, true);

    // Register with TickTimerService
    tick_timer_service_subscribe(MINUTE_UNIT, tick_handler);

    // Register callbacks
    app_message_register_inbox_received(inbox_received_callback);
    app_message_register_inbox_dropped(inbox_dropped_callback);
    app_message_register_outbox_failed(outbox_failed_callback);
    app_message_register_outbox_sent(outbox_sent_callback);

    // Open AppMessage
    app_message_open(app_message_inbox_size_maximum(), app_message_outbox_size_maximum());
}

static void deinit() {
    // Destroy Window
    window_destroy(s_main_window);
}

int main(void) {
    init();
    app_event_loop();
    deinit();
}
```

and here's the Javascript

```
var xhrRequest = function (url, type, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () {
        callback(this.responseText);
    };
    xhr.open(type, url);
    xhr.send();
};

function getStats() {
    // Construct URL
    var url = "http://crin.co.uk/stravaWatchface/getStats.php";

    // Send request to crin.co.uk
    xhrRequest(url, 'GET', 
    function(responseText) {
        // responseText contains a JSON object with stat info
        var json = JSON.parse(responseText);

        // Monthly miles
        var monthMiles = json.mM;
        console.log("Monthly total miles is: " + monthMiles);

        // Monthly Elevation
        var monthElevation = json.mE; 
        console.log("Monthly total elevation gain is: " + monthElevation);

        // Total Miles
        var totalMiles = json.tM; 
        console.log("All-time total miles is: " + totalMiles);

        // Total Elevation
        var totalElevation = json.tE; 
        console.log("All-time total elevation gain is: " + totalElevation);

        // Assemble dictionary using our keys
        var dictionary = {
            "KEY_MONTHMILES": monthMiles,
            "KEY_MONTHELEVATION": monthElevation,
            "KEY_TOTALMILES": totalMiles,
            "KEY_TOTALELEVATION": totalElevation
        };

        // Send to Pebble
        Pebble.sendAppMessage(dictionary,
        function(e) {
            console.log("Stats info sent to Pebble successfully!");
        },
        function(e) {
            console.log("Error sending stats info to Pebble!");
        }
        );
    } 
    );
}

// Listen for when the watchface is opened
Pebble.addEventListener('ready', 
function(e) {
    console.log("PebbleKit JS ready!");

    // Get the initial weather
    getStats();
}
);

// Listen for when an AppMessage is received
Pebble.addEventListener('appmessage',
function(e) {
    console.log("AppMessage received!");
    getStats();
} 
);
```

Anyone spot anything obvious? It compiles and installs fine, but this line...

```
text_layer_set_text(s_weather_layer, monthlyMiles_buffer);
```

Is updating the watchface with blank space and not the value it should.

Please help I've lost an afternoon to this.

Comment: Have you analyzed the logs? I would be interested in seeing what we see there, it will help identify how the app is executing and if we see anything wrong, we can use it to debug. The whole thing seems a bit funny. I feel like if you took something that worked and modified it with something more specific to your needs, then it may do with what you added. It appears that the url you are using returns a proper JSON object, so it must be something else. I look forward to seeing what the log shows